# Want to pass objects as a parameter in member function c++

Tags: c++

Hai

I have a class A,B,C now i have member function in class A which needs the objects of 
class B,C. Is it possible to achieve. If yes how?

```
class A 
{
  public:

  void fun(B obj_b,C obj_c)
  {

   }

} 

class B 
{
  //some work
} 

class C
{
  //some work
}


int main()
{
  B obj_b;
  C  obj_c;
  A obj_a;

  obj_a.fun(obj_b,obj_c); //I GET ERROR HERE DURING COMPILATION  
}
```

What is wrong in the above code?.

ERROR:

note: synthesized method first required here 
error:   initializing argument 1 of ‘void A::fun(B,C)’

Thank you

Comment: You'll have to provide the error too if you want help.

Comment: Too many syntax errors: `class` declarations need to be followed by a `;`, functions must have a return type (e.g. `int` for main) etc.

Comment: Ignore the syntax error. Tell me is it possible to execute

Comment: How about fixing the syntax error so we don't have to?

Comment: It is quite possible, but without the real error being shown its hard to know which particular problem the compiler is choking on... the Error that you have added is not the error, but a note printed by the compiler *after* the real error was printed. Provide the errors from the first one. (And also note that the missing `;` can choke the compiler and make it misinterpret the rest)

Answer (score 3):

If it's not a typo : Your function fun is ill-formed, the return type is missing.

```
void fun(B obj_b,C obj_c) // void was missing
  {

   }
```

And as other pointed, there are several other problem with this code as missing return type for main, missing `;` for class definitions, class B and class C must be declared before class A...

This last one seems to be what your error says.

Comment: another problem is, that the `class B` and `class C` _must_ be declared before `class A`.

Answer (score 2):

Might be because of class declaration..

At `void fun(B obj_b,C obj_c)` the compiler has no idea about `class B` and `class C`. So try giving like

```
class B 
{
  //some work
}; 

class C
{
  //some work
};

class A 
{
  public:

  void fun(B obj_b,C obj_c)
  {

   }

};
```

If the classes are in different header files, `#include` them in `class A`..

Hope it helps..

Answer (score 1):

The classes B and C are unknown in the `void fun(B obj_b,C obj_c)` line, you have to declare them first.

Either declare and define them first, if this is not possible (e.g. because they also need A), you can use *forward declarations*. It's just two single lines

```
class B;
class C;
```

BTW: With the method declaration `void fun(B obj_b,C obj_c)` you pass the parameters per value, what means that the objects B and C are copied. Most of the time this is not what u want: Pass them by reference by changing the method signature to `void fun(B& obj_b,C& obj_c)` .

Comment: If the objects are **passed by value** you **cannot forward declare** them. Also in referenced objects, only **if you are not accessing the referenced object's members**, you can forward declare them.

Answer (score 0):

After you correct all the syntax errors, you may encounter an error for the line declaring the  `fun` member function, saying that the classes `B` and `C` are not yet declared. Place a forward declaration for classes `B` and `C` before the `A` class declaration. That is, something like:

```
class B;  
class C;  
class A  
{  
public:
void fun(B obj_b, C obj_c)
... other stuff here
};
class B
{
... real declaration of the class B
};
class C
{
... real declaration of the class C
};
```

By the way, forward declarations are the only method of circularly-referenced class declarations.